# Can puppet type documentation be generated in machine readable format?

Tags: ruby, puppet, yard

Documentation for puppet's type is autogenerated (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.2.latest/type.html) using yardoc I suppose (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/tasks/yard.rake)

I there a way to tweak the tool to generate a format easily consumable by a computer program? (yaml/xml/..)

Comment: I don't actually think that the type docs are from YARD. YARD will create documentation about the source code from comments. The resource type documentation lives in actual code, by assigning strings to certain attributes of the type classes. There must be software that consumes this code (by actually loading the Puppet types and accessing the doc strings). So yes, it should not be hard to modify this to produce whatever format you need.